# Variable referenced before assignment error calling function

Tags: python, function

this is my code

```
def bv(a):

     if a >= 100000:
         bv = "1"
     elif a >= 50000 and a < 100000:
         bv = "2"
     elif a >= 20000 and a < 50000:
         bv = "3"
     elif a >= 10000 and a < 20000:
         bv = "4"
     elif a > 5000 and a < 10000:
         bv = "5"
    
     return bv
```

but when I call that function, I get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bv' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand why. I'm a beginner in python

Comment: What happens when a is negative?

Comment: Or any value 5000 or less?

Comment: What is `rec`? It doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: Also note that in every case, the `and a < <whatever>` part is redundant. You wouldn't get to that comparison if it were false.

Comment: @Sayse it does not matter in this case because a will never be negative. this is just a part of a larger script.

Comment: You need to give us the full error traceback, including the call site.

Comment: You should probably write something in your code to handle invalid values

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper indentation:

```py
def bv(a):

     if a >= 100000:
         bv = "1"
     elif a >= 50000 and a < 100000:
         bv = "2"
     elif a >= 20000 and a < 50000:
         bv = "3"
     elif a >= 10000 and a < 20000:
         bv = "4"
     elif a > 5000 and a < 10000:
         bv = "5"
     else:
         bv = ""
    
     return bv
```

The way you wrote it put the `return bv` outside of the function, and of course no variable `bv` exists outside of the function!

Also `rec` is not defined!

If indentation is not the problem, then none of your cases evaluate to true, you might want to add a default case. I added it to the code snipped.

Comment: A `return` outside a function would produce a different error.

Comment: Yes i realized! it probably needs a default case. I amended my answer

Comment: @Raphael im sorry it's actually idented in my code and I just forgot to replace rec but it's actually a. sorry for the confusion!